# Android activity without layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Is there any way to make Android layout with totally independent position of controls? Something like "free" layout in Java. I would like a layout in which position of controls wouldn't depend on anything other then position on which i dropped them from toolbox.
Is something like that possible in Android app?

Comment: No in android its not possible.

Comment: yes ofcaurse its not possible the way you saying but..you can check my answer..thats about the google release of Graphical Layout Editor

Answer (score 0):

Sure, RelativeLayout allows you to place your controls whereever you want on the display

Comment: but then, when i move one control, some other is moved too! I don't like that!

Comment: Sry, in most cases I work without the visual designer. So I'm not 100% sure that other controls aren't influenced in visual designer. But normally you are free to place your controls anywhere, without any restrictions to orientation (LinearLayout) or Grids/Tables (GridView/TableView) EDIT: Sry my fault. In the visual designer, the attributes leftOf, rightOf, below, above ...  are always set automatically. So you would have to position them in your xml code by hand

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the AbsoluteLayout which lets you specify the exact X and Y locations of the controls.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, better use RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Your choice would be:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, better use RelativeLayout